# How to filter with two criteria from two drop downs

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I am using a form with two comboboxes to select a 'primary' then a 'secondary' filter.

Separately the filters work. I can choose the primary or the secondary and it filters accordingly.

I want to join both into one filter.

```vb
Private Sub cmbSecondaryFilter_Click()

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbShowOnly.Value) Then ' making sure that the primary focus combo box isn't null
            
    subFilter = Me.ActiveControl.Column(0)
    classDept = Me.cmbShowOnly
               
    secondFilter = "Class_Department= '" & classDept & "'"  'this returns the correct filter criteria
    secondFilterB = "Current_Class_Number= '" & subFilter & "'" 'this returns the correct filter criteria

    Me.Filter = "" ' clear filter, chainging the secondary filter requires this to happen
    Me.FilterOn = True ' enable that filter - filter is clear
        
    'set filter
    'Me.Filter = secondFilter & " AND " & secondFilterB ' add new filter  ' this fails
    Me.Filter = "Me.[Class_Department]= '"& classDept & "' AND Me.[Current_Class_Number] = '"& subFilter & '"  ' this fails as well.

     ' how do I AND the two filters?
        
    Me.FilterOn = True ' enable the new filter
            
Else ' if primary filter is blank, exit sub

    MsgBox "Select a primary filter first.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbSecondaryFilter = ""

    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Your first filter concatenation should work. The Me. will definitely not. What does 'fails' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Precede the second FilterOn with FilterOff.

Comment: I thought so as well.  I remarked out the Me.[Class...] filter section.  The suggested filter prompts me for the data that I selected for the second drop down.  To be clear, I get a 'Enter Parameter Value' Prompt box with Current_Class_Number as the hint.  Which is the content of the secondFilterB variable in the code.  The values are present in the variables.  When filteron=true, the prompt occurs.

Comment: Code shows `Me.` filter line is active. However, this line should work if remove both `Me.` and make sure space in `" &`. Access triggers a prompt when it cannot find referenced object. I never use "Active...", should explicitly reference control. Don't need the `.Column(0)` part.

Comment: I got it to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmbSecondaryFilter_Click()

Dim secondaryFilter As String


If Not IsNull(Me.cmbShowOnly.Value) Then ' making sure that the primary focus combo box isn't null
            
        secondaryFilter = secondaryFilter & "([Class_Department]=""" & Me.cmbShowOnly & """) AND "
        
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbSecondaryFilter.Value) Then
    
        secondaryFilter = secondaryFilter & "([Current_Class_No] = """ & Me.cmbSecondaryFilter & """) "
        
End If
         
        'set filter
        Me.Filter = secondaryFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True ' enable the new filter
```

I have a ClearFilter button to allow the user to reset if they choose.  Also, if they choose a new cmbShowOnly, that code clears the cmbSecondaryFilter too.

I used the DB you posed as a guide. I was right, the apostrophe/quotes did me in initially.

Thanks for the help and the pointing in the right direction!